# In-place initialization risks

Tags: c++

Currently, I have a design that maps objects by a key, in an `unordered_map`. The problem is that in the constructor of this object, I need to look it up by the key- even though it doesn't exist yet. So far I have solved this problem by deferring everything, but it's quite awkward.

So I've been considering a kind of in-place-initializer. Something like

```
std::unordered_map<K, std::unique_ptr<T, FunkyDeleter>> map;
T* ptr = malloc(sizeof(T));
map[key] = std::unique_ptr<T, FunkyDeleter>(ptr);
try {
    new (ptr) T(args);
} catch(...) {
    map[key].release();
    map.erase(key);
    free(ptr);
    throw;
}
```

This way, code in T's constructor can look it up in the map, even though it's not fully constructed yet.

What are the risks and problems inherent in this design? So far I identified exception safety, the destructor for the `unique_ptr` is gonna be awkward, as well as the risks of accessing a half-constructed `T`.

Edit:

Roughly speaking, T represents a node in a graph which is very definitely not acyclic and never will be acyclic, ever. In T's constructor, to calculate some things about T, I wanted to look at T's subnodes- which can contain direct references to that T instance. Imagine something like

```
struct K {
    std::vector<K*> subkeys;
};
class T {
    std::vector<T*> child_nodes;
public:
    T(K* key, graph& graph) {
        for(auto subkey : keys->subkeys)
            child_nodes.push_back(graph.get(subkey));
    }
    std::vector<T*> children() { return child_nodes; }
};
class graph {
    std::unordered_map<K*, std::unique_ptr<T>> nodes;
public:
    T* get(K* key) {
        if (nodes.find(key) == nodes.end())
            nodes[key] = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(key, *this));
        return nodes[key].get();
    }
};
int main() {
    graph g;
    K key1;
    K key2;
    key1.subkeys.push_back(&key2);
    key2.subkeys.push_back(&key1);
    g.get(&key1);
}
```

This obviously doesn't work in the case of cyclic references in K objects. The problem is how I'm going to support them. So far I simply deferred all work so that `T` simply does not evaluate any potentially referencing code in the constructor, but that leads to some very awkward designs in some places. I wanted to try and place the pointer to the T into the map as it's being constructed, so that circular references evaluate correctly in the constructor and I can throw out this deferred work, as some of it actually has important side-effects (which I cannot avoid due to a third-party design) and managing deferred side-effects is a bitch.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more context?  Where is the above code located and what are the various parameters?  What is the scope of `map`?  Currently, it seems to me that simply using a default-constructed `std::unique_ptr<T>` would be a simple solution but I'm not sure I fully understand your situation.

Comment: *"in the constructor of this object, I need to look it up by the key"* You probably have a good reason for this claim. Would you mind elaborating on that part?

Comment: One of them is the UB in mixing `std::unique_ptr` (which does `delete`) with `malloc` (whose pendant is `free` instead).

Comment: IIRC, in `map[key] = std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr);`, `map[key]` can be executed after `std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr)`. I suppose you would supply a custom deleter which essentially does `p->~T(); free(p);`. But if `map[key]` throws an exception (e.g. OOM) after `std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr)` has been evaluated, you'll get UB. Is that what you're describing in the last paragraph with "the destructor for the `unique_ptr` is gonna be awkward"? Of course, this scenario can be prevented e.g. by using `auto& uptr = map[key]; uptr = std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr);`

Comment: @dyp: I'm not too concerned about OOM. I simply meant that I knew that I'd have to supply a custom deleter for the unique_ptr and that managing exactly when the object is deleted is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you have such tight dependencies, in general constructor and destructor easily become a mess.

In general, you should avoid such things. Sometimes, it's just clearer to construct objects in an invalid state, and then initialize them with an `initialize` method. If you have some instance fields that you would like to be `const`, you can group them in a non-const `struct` field with `const` fields, that it assigned by `initialize`. You can even define some form of `optional` which can never be assigned more than once, but maybe that's overshooting.

Getting back to the question, what I see is:

1. The destructor of `unique_ptr` will call `delete` on a pointer which was not allocated with `new`, which is undefined behavior. You should use a unique_ptr with a dedicated/noop deallocator, unless you can control all the code which might remove that thing from the map, and be sure it uses that same `release-erase-free` boilerplate you used in your `catch` clause.
2. `unique_ptr` is meant to also work with incomplete types, so it will not try to access your object, and your `T*` is segregated inside the function. So you can only access a partially constructed `T` if:

   - `T`'s constructor itself leaks a reference (this would be independent from your code here), or
   - Someone other thread tries to lookup for the new item. Doesn't seem to be the case, if your map is also local to the function. If you're doing multithread, then you **must** change your design, unless performance are not important. Because the only thing to do here is a reentrant mutex lock on the map, which would destroy all benefits you could get from multithreading.

#### EDIT

In response to your edit. First of all, it seems clean to me. Doesn't look like you're doing something weird. But you have to deal with the destructor problem, because your map will eventually get destroyed (program termination also causes destructors to be called).

Anyway:

1. I think you're using keys in a weird way. If the key itself already contains information about the subnodes, why are you also duplicating that information in the node itself? Information duplication calls for out-of-sync-data bugs.
2. Can't you just change `T` constructor to check the `subkey` before the lookup, and avoid looking for its own `key`?

Comment: The map is insert-only. As for the circular lookup, the work of T fundamentally requires supporting circular lookups. The only question is if I can move some of this work into the constructor. I also do not currently support concurrency in the graph, and if I did, it would involve serializing this aspect anyway, as the graph's semantics require that every lookup returns the same T.

Comment: Data can only become out of sync if it can be mutated, which the input can't. It's not really a duplication because the lookup can be a lot more complex- the point of the graph is to represent the input in a more useful way. I can't really check for this before the lookup because there are many ways to reference the same object. The only way to determine what node the key corresponds to is to try to look it up, and by that point, it's too late.

Comment: Bugs are fun because they contradict what you think would be an invariant. Maybe some code edits the graph by mistake (or because a programmer didn't understand the documentation) if anything in there isn't `const`, or someone makes some mistake while implementing some new feature in this very initialization code code. In general, I think having more representations for the same thing is to be classified as potential bug, and avoided, unless strictly needed. I didn't say your case falls in the "non strictly needed", I just suggested you to think about it.